# Centering Tkinter MessageBox in the middle of the screen without using other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Ive looked everywhere for a way of doing this. I am making a database style program which is using the tkinter, sqlite3 and datetime modules. I dont have access to other many other modules as the computer I am working on does not have the right ones installed. I have tried using win32api and gtk but they are not installed and i cannot install them easily. I am looking for a way of using tkinter to centre the messagebox in the middle of the screen every-time a window is opened. Anyone know a way?

Comment: ...You have looked everywhere but the documentation itself? `tkinter` have various [`.winfo_screen...`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_screen-method) methods that gives you the information of the screen where you can work your way back to the center.

Comment: i didnt come across .winfo_screen. ill look into that now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query `tkinter` to learn the screen width `scr_w` and widget width `wdg_w`. Then `x_offset = scr_w / 2 - wdg_w / 2`. Or perhaps you prefer to pull out the .5 coefficient: `(scr_w - wdg_w) / 2`.

Similarly for the heights: `y_offset = (scr_h - wdg_h) / 2`